# How to find the remaining subgroup after some Higgs field gets a VEV?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

Say we have a group $G$ and a set of Higgs fields in a representation $R$ of $G$. One of the Higgs fields in $R$ gets a VEV, how can I determine **the** remaining subgroup after this symmetry breaking?

In the standard model things are easy, because the Higgs field that gets a VEV has nonzero Isospin and Hypercharge, but zero Electric Charge. Therefore $$SU(2)\otimes U(1)_Y \rightarrow U(1)_Q$$

There is no room for ambiguities.

Nevertheless, for some bigger group it's not sufficient to know that the corresponding Higgs field has zero charge under the corresponding subgroup $G'$ because there can be some bigger subgroup $G' \subset G''$ under which the Higgs field has zero charge, too.

This task is commonly called "finding the maximal little group" and I'm looking for a concrete way of determine this "maximal little group" if some Higgs field gets a VEV.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: In general it depends how the Higgs take his vev, as the maximal (*some adjective*) subgroup of a given group can depend on the embedding.

Comment: @Oscar What do you mean by "how the Higgs take his vev"? For simplicity let's say only one Higgs field $\Phi$ inside the representation $R$ gets a VEV and the embedding has been fixed. My problem is determining the subgroup $G'$ to which my starting group $G$ is broken to by this $\Phi \rightarrow VEV$. A necessary but not sufficient condition is that $\Phi$ is a singlet under $G'$ but a non-singlet under $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start with a group $G$ which is a symmetry of the theory (ie of Lagrangian) there will be some generators for $G$. Call them $T_1,\ldots,T_N$. In the original Lagrangian, (before the Higgs gets a vev) you can do a transformation with any of the $T_i$'s and the Lagrangian will not change. After the field gets a vev, you can try the same and you will find some of the $T_i$'s still leave the Lagrangian unchanged (*unbroken generators*) and some of them do not (*broken generators*). The remaining subgroup after the symmetry breaking is simply the group generated by the unbroken generators.

I would recommend chapter 84 of [Srednicki's book](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) for more details and some examples.