# Symmetry breaking to a special subalgebra?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192274/how-to-find-the-remaining-subgroup-after-some-higgs-field-gets-a-vev#comment408980_192274).

- For **regular subalgebras** of some group's Lie algebra the root system of the subalgebra is a subset of the root system of the original's group algebra. In other words, the generators of the subalgebra are a subset of the generators of the original group.
- Subalgebras whose root system is not a subset of the root system of the original algebra are called **special subalgebras**. Therefore, the generators are not a subset of the original's group generators.

Using the Higgs mechanism, as explained nicely by @Heterotic in the question I linked to above, we simply check which generators remain unbroken after one or more Higgs fields get a vev. Then:

> "The remaining subgroup after the symmetry breaking is simply the
>   group generated by the unbroken generators."

This is certainly correct for regular subalgebras, but how does this work for special subalgebras? How can we determine that we broke to a special subalgebra by giving a vev to a Higgs field, if the generators of the subalgebra are not a subset of the original's group generators?

Comment: It might be easier to consider an answer if you provided a simple, concise, explicit example of a special subalgebra of a small Lie Algebra. Your definition of such is prima facie puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

> Subalgebras whose root system is not a subset of the root system of
>   the original algebra are called special subalgebras. **Therefore, the
>   generators are not a subset of the original's group generators**.

That is not quite right. A special subalgebra is one such that their step operators do not form a subset of the algebra step operators.That is what is meant by a root system not being a subset of another root system. It does not imply that the subalgebra generators are not a subset of the algebra generators.

Example: Consider the three dimensional representation of $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{su}(3)$, whose generators $T_a=\lambda_a/2$, where $\lambda_a$ are the [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices). The step operators are
\begin{align*}
E_{\pm\alpha_1}=T_1\pm iT_2,\\
E_{\pm\alpha_2}=T_6\pm iT_7,\\
E_{\pm(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)}=T_4\pm iT_5,
\end{align*}
**Regular embedding:** The generators $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ form a subalgebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. This subalgebra step operators are $t_\pm=T_1\pm iT_2=E_{\pm\alpha_1}$. The subalgebra step operators form a subset of the algebra step operators.

**Special embedding:** Another $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ subalgebra is given by $T_2$, $T_5$ and $T_7$. In this case the step operators are $t_\pm=T_5\pm iT_7$ which cannot be written in terms of the step operators of $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.

Notice the branching rules for the first embedding is $3=2\oplus 1$ while for the second is $3=3$.